# Setting argc/argv and including a PHP CLI script

Tags: php

If I've got a CLI script foo written in PHP that requires various command line options, can I invoke foo from another PHP script by first writing to $argv and $argc and then doing `include('foo')`? (Assume foo starts with `<?php`, not a hash-bang directive.)

Even if this would "work", why is it a bad idea? (apart from namespace collision).

Comment: argc/argv in title, instead of argv/argv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to write anything into `$argv` /`$argc` - the variables will be available to the include like they are to the main script.

Comment: hi Pekka! assume foo’s CLI options are independent of the calling script’s options. the calling script figures out what foo’s options need to be and then calls it. normally i’d use exec to invoke a CLI command from a PHP script. then it occurred to me that if the CLI command is written in PHP, why not include it?

Comment: @fsb I see. Mmm, rewriting $argv is probably possible, but it sounds like bad practice to me. I would rather use a dedicated different array in that case

Answer (score 0):

If you don't allow user input for these command-line arguments, or are very careful with them, you could always use the [system](https://www.php.net/system) or [exec](https://www.php.net/exec) functions to call foo, explicitly with those arguments, and without messing around with $argc and $argv.

That is, so long as you don't actually need foo explicitly included..

I imagine what you're suggesting would work, just don't forget to put the old values back.

Comment: yes, system/exec/passthru are normally how i run scripts from within scripts.